# Test for my topological/dependancy sort

Tags: python, dependency-injection, language-agnostic, dependencies, dependency-management

This is more of a puzzle than a question per se, because I think I already have the right answer - I just don't know how to test it (if it works under all scenarios).

My program takes input from user about which modules it will need to load (in the form of an unsorted list or set). Some of those modules depend on other modules. The way module-dependancy information is stored is in a dictionary like this:

```
all_modules = { 'moduleE':[], 'moduleD':['moduleC'], 'moduleC':['moduleB'], 'moduleB':[], 'moduleA':['moduleD'] }
```

Where moduleE has no dependancies, and moduleD depends on moduleC, etc...

Also, there is no definitive lists of all possible modules, since the users can generate their own, and I create new ones from time to time, so this solution has to be fairly generic (and thus tested to work in all cases).

What I want to do is to get a list of modules to run in order, such that modules that are dependant on other modules are only run after their dependancies.

So I wrote the following code to try and do this:

```
def sort_dependencies(modules_to_sort,all_modules,recursions):
    ## Takes a small set of modules the user wants to run (as a list) and 
    ## the full dependency tree (as a dict) and returns a list of all the
    ## modules/dependencies needed to be run, in the order to be run in.
    ## Cycles poorly detected as recursions going above 10. 
    ## If that happens, this function returns False.
    if recursions == 10:
        return False
    result = []
    for module in modules_to_sort:
        if module not in result:
            result.append(module)
        dependencies = all_modules[module]
        for dependency in dependencies:
            if dependency not in result:
                result.append(dependency)
            else:
                result += [ result.pop(result.index(dependency)) ]
        subdependencies = sort_dependencies(dependencies, all_modules, recursions+1)
        if subdependencies == False:
            return False
        else:
            for subdependency in subdependencies:
                if subdependency not in result:
                    result.append(subdependency)
                else:
                    result += [ result.pop(result.index(subdependency)) ]
    return result
```

And it works like this:

```
>>> all_modules = { 'moduleE':[], 'moduleD':['moduleC'], 'moduleC':['moduleB'], 'moduleB':[], 'moduleA':['moduleD'] }
>>> sort_dependencies(['moduleA'],all_modules,0)
['moduleA', 'moduleD', 'moduleC', 'moduleB']
```

Note that 'moduleE' isn't returned, since the user doesn't need to run that.

Question is - does it work for any given all_modules dictionaries and any given required modules_to_load list? Is there a dependancy graph I can put in and a number of user-module-lists to try that, if they work, I can say all graphs/user-lists will work?

---

---

After the excellent advice by Marshall Farrier, it looks like i'm trying to do is a topological sort, so after watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfSk24UTFS8) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jksMzq4LgfM) I implemented that as the following:

***EDIT: Now with cyclic dependancy checking!***

```
def sort_dependencies(all_modules):
    post_order = []
    tree_edges = {}
    for fromNode,toNodes in all_modules.items():
        if fromNode not in tree_edges:
            tree_edges[fromNode] = 'root'
            for toNode in toNodes:
                if toNode not in tree_edges:
                    post_order += get_posts(fromNode,toNode,tree_edges)
            post_order.append(fromNode)
    return post_order

def get_posts(fromNode,toNode,tree_edges):
    post_order = []
    tree_edges[toNode] = fromNode
    for dependancy in all_modules[toNode]:
        if dependancy not in tree_edges:
            post_order += get_posts(toNode,dependancy,tree_edges)
        else:
            parent = tree_edges[toNode]
            while parent != 'root':
                if parent == dependancy: print 'cyclic dependancy found!'; exit()
                parent = tree_edges[parent]
    return post_order + [toNode]

sort_dependencies(all_modules)
```

However, a topological sort like the one above sorts the whole tree, and doesn't actually return just the modules the user needs to run. Of course having the topological sort of the tree helps solve this problem, but it's not really the same question as the OP. I think for my data, the topological sort is probably best, but for a huge graph like all packages in apt/yum/pip/npm, it's probably better to use the original algorithm in the OP (which I don't know if it actually works in all scenarios...) as it only sorts what needs to be used.

So i'm leaving the question up an unanswered, because the question is really "How do i test this?"

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Python will import the necessary modules at the necessary times.

Comment: These aren't strictly python modules. It's small bits of code that the user writes into files, typically a single class object. Inside that module class, it specifies it's unique name, and it's dependancies by name. This file gets executed with execfile(). Sometimes the modules are fetched out of an SQL database over the internet, so not even in a file.

Comment: So really i'm just looking for a general solution to figure out how to know the linear order of module execution for a tree-shaped module-dependency list like the simple dictionary example, for one more more given modules. Really, it is only barely a python question :)

Comment: This looks to me like topological sort, which follows from a depth-first search.

Comment: @zondo; I'm not the OP but I have a similar need that lead me to that question. Basically I have a complex configuration leading to a segfault depending if I'm importing some modules before or after a call to fork(). The problem is raised by a deep import of a library module, henceforth I need a way to easily know all deep imports and comment/uncomment them one after the other until the system crash (in my case the faulty module was twisted.reactor). Another use case is checking if deep imports are causing unwanted module loading needing to be fixed.